# Отрисовка графиков в RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Помогите пожалуйста с отрисовкой графика, нужно что-то похожее, как на картинке. Очень нужна помощь. Заранее благодарю за помощь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Алгоритм метода потенциальных функций

```
potentialFunction <- function(distances, potentials, h, xl, type_core) {
  l <- nrow(xl)
  n <- ncol(xl)
  classes <- xl[, n]
  weights <- table(classes) 
  weights[1:length(weights)] <- 0 
  for (i in 1:l) { 
    class <- xl[i, n] 
    r <- distances[i] / h[i]
    weights[class] <- weights[class] + potentials[i] * type_core(r) 
  }
  if (max(weights) != 0) return (names(which.max(weights))) 
  return (0) 
}
```

Алгоритм поиска потенциала

```
getPotentials <- function(xl, h, eps, type_core)
{
  l <- nrow(xl) # строки
  n <- ncol(xl) # столбцы (размерность)
  potentials <- rep(0, l)
  distances_to_points <- matrix(0, l, l)
  err <- eps + 1  
    
  for (i in 1:l)
    distances_to_points[i,] <- getDistances(xl, c(xl[i, 1], xl[i, 2])) 
  # xl - выборка, xl[i] - текущая точка и её координата
  while(err > eps){
    while (TRUE) {
      
      cur <- sample(1:l, 1) 
      class <- potentialFunction(distances_to_points[cur, ], potentials, h, xl, type_core)

      if (class != xl[cur, n]) { # если не соответсвует классу
    potentials[cur] = potentials[cur] + 1 
    break
      } #if
    } #while(true)

    
    err <- 0
    for (i in 1:l) {
      class <- potentialFunction(distances_to_points[i, ], potentials, h, xl, type_core)
      err <- err + (class != xl[i, n])
    }
  }
  return (potentials)
}
```